# How to start node.js socket.io server from within a brackets extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, plugins, socket.io, adobe-brackets

I'm trying to write a brackets extension in which data is send to a server. In the main.js file I want to execute a server.js file in which I create a node.js socket.io server. When it is finished, the extension should be able to send data to that server.

My directory looks like this:

```
|-- myExtensionFolder
    |-- node
        |-- node_modules
        |-- server.js
    |-- main.js
    |-- package.json
```

My server.js file currently contains this:

```
var server = require("http").createServer(),
socket = require("socket.io")(server);

socket.on("connect", function(){
    console.log("connected");
});

socket.on("event", function(data){
    console.log("event");
});

socket.on("disconnect", function(){
    console.log("disconnected");
});

server.listen(3000);
```

And my main.js file contains this:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    console.log("start extension");

    // The CommandManager registers command IDs with functions
    var CommandManager = brackets.getModule("command/CommandManager"),
    // This holds the list of all default commands
    Commands = brackets.getModule("command/Commands");

    var serverModule = require("node/server");
    //I'm trying to get the server.js file here and would like to somehow execute it 
})
```

So my question is: How can I start the server from the server.js file inside the main.js file?

And if some of you are wondering why I don't have an index.html file... I'm not going to need a website, only a server where I can transfer data.

Answer (score 0):

The main code of Brackets and your extension runs in a Chromium environment.
If you want to execute something in a node context, you have to implement a [`NodeDomain`](http://brackets.io/docs/current/modules/utils/NodeDomain.html).

*domain.js*:

```
var _domainManager;
var DOMAIN_NAME = "kerstinsServer";

function start() {
    var server = require("http").createServer(),
        socket = require("socket.io")(server);

    socket.on("connect", function () {
        _domainManager.emitEvent(DOMAIN_NAME, "out", "connected");
    });
}

function init(domainManager) {
    _domainManager = domainManager;
    if (!domainManager.hasDomain(DOMAIN_NAME)) {
        domainManager.registerDomain(DOMAIN_NAME, {
            major: 0,
            minor: 1
        });
    }
    domainManager.registerCommand(
        DOMAIN_NAME, // domain name
        "start", // command name
        start, // command handler function
        false, // this command is synchronous in Node
        "Starts the server"
    );
}
```

*main.js*:

```
define(function (require, exports, module) {
    "use strict";

    var ExtensionUtils = brackets.getModule("utils/ExtensionUtils");
    var NodeDomain = brackets.getModule("utils/NodeDomain");
    var nodeDomain = new NodeDomain("kerstinsServer", ExtensionUtils.getModulePath(module, "domain"));

    nodeDomain.exec("start");
    nodeDomain.on("out", function (event, message) {
        console.log(message);
    });
});
```

See the [developer guide](https://github.com/adobe/brackets/wiki/Brackets-Node-Process:-Overview-for-Developers) for details.